# How do range queries work for clustering keys in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

According to the official doc:
Clustering columns order data within a partition. When a table has multiple clustering columns the data is stored in nested sort order.

Suppose we have simple timeseries table:

```
CREATE TABLE alerts_by_year(
  year int,
  ts timestamp,
  alert text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((year), ts)
);
```

A simple query that get events for some range:

```
SELECT * FROM alerts_by_year
  WHERE year=2022
  AND ts >'2022-06-24 03:11:00'
  AND ts <'2022-06-24 04:11:00'
```

What is algorithm complexity to find this range through the "ts" clustering keys?
Is it constant time or O(n) time?
Does it depends on the type of storage used: memtable or sstable?

How does it work then? Are we simply iterating through "ts" clustering keys until we find the required range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering columns are stored in sorted order. If you don't explicitly specify the order when you create a table, the clustering columns will be sorted in ascending order.

In your case, the following table option is automatically added to your table's definition:

```
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts ASC)
```

In your case, the table schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE alerts_by_year(
  year int,
  ts timestamp,
  alert text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((year), ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts ASC)
```

Since the rows in each partition is sorted in chronological order from oldest to newest timestamp, a range query on the `ts` column is done sequentially, iterating one row at a time until the condition is satisfied.

Note that the drivers will automatically page through the results. For example, [the Java driver will return the first 5000 rows by default](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/paging/). You app will then need to retrieve the "next page" to get the next set of rows. Cheers!

Comment: I have a question.Why sequential search here? As data is sorted, we can have binary search too, isn't?

Comment: @Mandroid we don't do follow-up questions in the comments section because they'll end up being a never-ending thread.  Please post a new question instead. Cheers!